# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, google-client, google-shopping-api

I am calling this method:

```
GoogleTokenResponse accessResposnse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                clientId, clientSecret, authorizationUrl, redirectUrl).execute();
```

where authorizationUrl is:

```
String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, scope).setAccessType("offline").setState("security_token").setResponseTypes(responseType).build();
```

But it's giving me the error:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request 
>     {
>       "error" : "invalid_grant" 
>     }

Am I missing any step in between?
Also if I am trying to call this function:

```
AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl authoUrl = new AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl(redirectUrl);
```

It's throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your refresh token is expired.. are you trying to refresh your access token with an expired refresh token or making an api call with an expired refresh token? - if so you need to make your user re-authenticate..